# Internet Explorer saving the wrong input as password

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, passwords, forms

I'm trying to make a login form that submits an encrypted password to the server, while setting the plaintext it on hidden fields outside the form.

In Chrome/Firefox, it remembers the login/password set in the hidden fields, while in IE, it remembers the encrypted password.

I'd like to know how can I work around this.

here's what I have:

```
<script>
    function encryptPassword() {
        var txtUsername= document.getElementById("txtUsername");
        var txtPassword= document.getElementById("txtPassword");

        document.getElementById('username').value = txtUsername.value;
        document.getElementById('password').value = txtPassword.value;

        txtPassword.value = encrypt(md5(txtPassword.value), "<%=pubKey %>");
    }
</script>

<div style="visibility: hidden">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:0;height:0" tabindex="-1" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:0;height:0" tabindex="-1" />
</div>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" autofocus="autofocus" required="required"  runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" required="required" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnOk_Click" OnClientClick="encryptPassword();" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor button and instead of pasting ASP, paste HTML and JS only into a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, but the snippet editor doesn't seem to recognize ASP, as it is required to understand my problem.

Comment: Your issue looks like it is form/HTML/JavaScript only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing encrypted password in `txtPassword` before posting it to server that's why `I.E` is storing it. You can store encrypted password in hidden field and retrieve it from there during authentication.

Replace this line

```
txtPassword.value = encrypt(md5(txtPassword.value), "<%=pubKey %>");
```

something

```
hfPassword.value = encrypt(md5(txtPassword.value), "<%=pubKey %>");
```

where `hfPassword` will be the hidden field and you will have to add it to the form.

I will be saved as encrypted text. Don't save txtPassword value. Save hfPassword instead. txtPassword  will only be used for user interaction and input to the encryption function.

Comment: but then the password will be submitted to the server as plaintext as well, I'm not planning on buying a https cert.

Comment: No. I will be saved as encrypted text. Don't save txtPassword value. Save hfPassword instead. txtPassword  will only be used for user interaction and input to the encryption function.

Comment: but if the txtPassword is inside the form when the form is submitted, it will be submitted as well. But I'm already working on a solution that involves setting `disabled='disabled'` before submitting, and unsetting it if there's any error